# call Function in specific time interval using pthread in linux c++

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I want to call function in specific time (2 micro second) interval using pthread in linux c++.

I want to call this function inside pthread till some specific condition occur after that rest of the code inside the thread is run. this procedure occur continue.

please give some solution or example code ??

Comment: In a loop, have the thread sleep two micro-seconds, and then call the function?

Comment: What about using a condition and wait for this condition? pthread_cond_wait

Answer (score 0):

[`usleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep)

Use a for loop and call your function, after/before it, put [`usleep`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep).

> The **usleep()** function suspends execution of the calling thread for (at least) usec microseconds. The sleep may be lengthened slightly by any system activity or by the time spent processing the call or by the granularity of system timers.

Comment: @parth9966 The `usleep` function puts the calling *thread* to sleep, the rest of your process still keeps on running. And if you to multiple things in the thread, why not use *multiple* threads, one that does whatever processing is needed, and one that does the timeouts?

Comment: @parth9966 Otherwise, how about [`setitimer`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setitimer.2.html)?

Comment: @joachim yes setitimer with signal

Answer (score 0):

We can have a look at the snippet from [this great article on threads](https://vcansimplify.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/pthread-tutorial-simplified/):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
 
void* say_hello(void* data)
{
    char *str;
    str = (char*)data;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("%s\n",str);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
 
void main()
{
    pthread_t t1,t2;
 
    pthread_create(&t1,NULL,say_hello,"hello from 1");
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL,say_hello,"hello from 2");
    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
}
```

As of now the **say_hello** function is run in a thread forever because of the  **while(1)** loop. One can modify the loop to break when some condition is true (counter, some variable value change, time elapsed, etc.).

What to do after this function exits? One can modify the **main** function to have a thread for **say_hello** created in a loop (endlessly, if needed). Btw, the second thread creation (as in the example) is not needed.

Hope this helps anyone who is looking for an answer to this ancient question.